# Neos CMS 7: Newly created node disappears in the document tree until cache cleared

Tags: neoscms

Is the document tree cached in the Neos CMS backend? I have created two pages under "Home": "Neos CMS" and "Blog" and they are displayed correctly in the main menu of the page preview, but when I click on one of the two page nodes in the document tree, the "Blog" node disappears in the document tree. Only when I click on the "Home" node or the tree refresh button, the "Blog" node temporarily reappears. When flushing the cache via CLI command `./flow flow:cache:flush` the node becomes permanently visible.

This behavior is browser independent; normally I use Firefox, just now I used Vivaldi with default settings.

I used the [CodeQ Skeleton](https://github.com/code-q-web-factory/Neos-Skeleton) as the base distribution, but others have confirmed the behavior for the official [Neos Base Distribution](https://github.com/neos/neos-base-distribution) as well.

I can provide a bash script that builds up a Neos instance for repeating reproduction of this behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

Just for reference here is the link to the Github issue https://github.com/neos/neos-ui/issues/3248

Best would be to reproduce the issue without the Skeleton Package.
I'm not aware of anything in the cache that should influence the document tree. Maybe it's another plugin installed with the Skeleton distribution.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was fixed by this PR:
https://github.com/code-q-web-factory/Neos-Skeleton/pull/30/files

**Problem description:**
Newly created documents would vanish in the document tree and would only become visible after a hard reload. The issue is rooted in the fact, that the footer is inline editable, however the context node is the site node.

**Solution:**
To prevent this behavior, the footer is now only inline editable on the home page, where site == documentNode.

Comment: Is there any background information on why the previous implementation caused the caching issues?

Comment: From the PR description: Newly created documents would vanish in the document tree and would only become visible after a hard reload. The issue is rooted in the fact, that the footer is inline editable, however the context node is the site node.

To prevent this behavior, the footer is now only inline editable on the home page, where site == documentNode.

Comment: If you add the info from that comment to the answer post itself you likely increase the perceived helpfulness.